# How to set a button's parameters programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a bunch of buttons to a layout like this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    Button button = new Button( this );
    button.setText( "" + i );
    ( ( LinearLayout )dialog.findViewById( R.id.Buttons ) ).addView( button );
}
```

My problem is how do I do this programmatically to all the buttons:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="32dip" />
```

I've been looking at LayoutParams but it doesn't look complete.  Like how do I set the textSize to 32 dip?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set your attributes using the following code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
button.setTextSize(32);
```

If you want to specify the text size units use:

```
button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the gravity though.  setGravity( Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL ) does not do the same as android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in the xml file.  The xml file button is centered, but not the ones created with setGravity().

Comment: Try this with the layout params:  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: Or after initializing params call: params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

Comment: The reason setGravity doesn't work the way you want is because android:gravity is different than android:layout_gravity

Comment: Thanx, but I figured it out. Instead of setting layout_gravity on each button, I set gravity on the parent view LinearLayout.

Comment: That works too. Saves you from setting the value on each button.

Answer (score 4):

`LayoutParams` relates to the parent `ViewGroup` which will contain the view. So in your case it's a `LinearLayout` so you need to create parameters for that one. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.weight = 1f;

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(lp);
button.setText("" + i);
((LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.Buttons)).addView(button);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use LayoutParams for the height, width and gravity with

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams (int width, int height)
```

where you can use `WRAP_CONTENT` for the ints.

Then there are `Button.setGravity()` and `Button.setTextSize()` for the last two.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I specify dip by using Button.setTextSize()?

Comment: public void setTextSize (int unit, float size);
where unit is "COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP" and size = the text size.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a `LayoutParams` object for the layout settings, and to set the text size use [setTextSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29) from the `Button` class.

You can set the gravity with [setGravity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29) too.

Answer (score 0):

TextSize is not inside Layout params. To set textSize you have to

```
button.setTextSize(32);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking to modify existing parameters, you get the LayoutParams from the Button and typecast it to the type of layout that the button is inside of:

```
//get the current params and typecast to whichever layout the button is in
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
//change something in the params
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 200);
//set the button with the new params
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```