# Programmatically set ImageButton layout_gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

## What I Tried To Do

I tried to set my `ImageButton`'s `layout_gravity` via Java code, the way I want the `ImageButton` to be is presented like the way within the **Orange** frame in the image below:

[image]

The **Blue** frame is a vertical `LinearLayout` act as a "base" layout and this is the layout I tried to add child layouts to.

The **Orange** and **Red** are both horizontal `LinearLayout`.

The **Orange** layout is the way I want to put the `ImageButton` and the `TextView`, this one is set up via XML

The **Red** layout is the result I tried to mimic the **Orange** layout via Java code.

## The Related Code

Here's the XML code that set up the **Orange** layout, **this is the effect I want to achieve via Java code:**

```
        <!-- Begin the Orange Layout -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/info_left_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/info_right_padding" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/detail_min_line_item_height"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:maxHeight="@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/navigation_cancel" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here's the Java code that set up the **Red** layout

```
        int textHeight = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.detail_min_line_item_height);
        int imgHeight = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abs__action_bar_default_height);

        TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
        ImageButton mDeleteButton = new ImageButton(this);

        // Set Delete Button Padding
//      mDeleteButton.setPadding(buttonPadding, buttonPadding, buttonPadding, buttonPadding);

        // Set Imagebutton Scale type as fitCentre
        mDeleteButton.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        // Set AdjustViewBounds
        mDeleteButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        // Set max height of the image
        mDeleteButton.setMaxHeight(imgHeight);

        // Set the text appearance to be "large"
        mTextView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
        mTextView.setText(text);

        // Set the minimum height of this textview
        mTextView.setMinHeight(textHeight);

        // Set the content of the textview to be centred
        mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        // Set the ImageButton's background image
        mDeleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.navigation_cancel);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams hParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout hLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // Set Margins
        hParams.leftMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.info_left_padding);
        hParams.rightMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.info_right_padding);
        hParams.bottomMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_layout_margin);

        hLayout.setLayoutParams(hParams);
        // Set orientation to horizontal
        hLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // The settings below is actually setting up some of the button's parameters        
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        mDeleteButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

        hLayout.addView(mTextView);
        hLayout.addView(mDeleteButton);

        layout_blue.addView(hLayout);
```

## What I've Tried So Far

According to some SO post like this: [Java method for android:layout_gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945315/java-method-for-androidlayout-gravity) I initially tried to first put my `ImageButton` into a `FrameLayout` then set the params of this `FrameLayout`, like this:

```
FrameLayout buttonFrame = new FrameLayout(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                                            android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                                                            Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
buttonFrame.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
buttonFrame.addView(mDeleteButton);
```

But I had the same result as the image presented above. Later I also tried to change the `LayoutParams` width to MATCH_PARENT`only to find the`ImageButton` was stretched horizontally (Yes it's stretched)

Then I tried the method posted in these two SO posts:

[How to set layout_gravity programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049620/how-to-set-layout-gravity-programmaticaly/8049860#8049860)

[How to set a button's parameters programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127704/how-to-set-a-buttons-parameters-programatically)

Their method is to set up a `LinearLayout.Params` first, then apply this params to the button (The Code I posted in **The Related Code** section applies this method). In short it is:

```
    // The settings below is actually setting up some of the button's parameters        
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buttonParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    mDeleteButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
```

However, the result was still the same as the image presented above.

## Question

Since I need to programmatically add more child views to the **Blue** layout later, I wonder if there's a way to set up each child layout like the **Orange** one in the image?

**At Last**

I found a solution which is quite similar to @Permita 's answer.

Here's my solution:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textParams.weight = 1.0f;
    mTextView.setLayoutParams(textParams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code, it will assign all the available space to the texView, shifting the button to right side of the layout to make it appear like the orangeLayout.

```
mTextView.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
```

Comment: actually I've found the solution which is quite similar to yours: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  textParams.weight = 1.0f;
  mTextView.setLayoutParams(textParams);`

Answer (score 0):

Try layout_width = "0dp" layout_weight="1" for the TextView. This tells TextView to occupy the whole available width, so that FrameLayout with ImageView will align to the right border.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/detail_min_line_item_height"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm afraid you didn't fully understand my question...I'm trying to set up a layout via Java code to achieve the same result as the XML. The RED frame is the result I tried via Java code, and the ORANGE frame is the effect I want to achieve, which is done by XML without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the standard `LinearLayout`, why not try to use the more complex `RelativeLayout`? With it, you can adjust the locations of each individual view relative to others. You can set the `ImageButton` in the orange layout to `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`, which will set the button attached to the right side of the parent layout, the `RelativeLayout` in my case, but the `LinearLayout` in yours. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) is the link to the API Guides for Relative Layouts on the Android developers website.